# Is it possible to migrate from Laravel Sanctum to Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-passport, laravel-sanctum

I am wondering if it is possible to migrate from sanctum to passport and how to migrate.

Comment: I would say yes, it's possible, but it depends on what you mean by migrating. The first thing I would do to know how, is a search to find information about it.

Comment: Laravel Sanctum and Laravel Passport are on the surface appear similar but are completely different under the covers. If you know Laravel well, yes, it is possible. For anything beyond a simple project, migrating would be a challenge.

Comment: entirely depends on what your using them for, for basic API auth yes you can easily